# Wordpress: redirecting to wp-admin/install.php even after reinstalling backup of a version that for sure worked

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm having major difficulties to regaining access to my wordpress website (was online for 2 years) and to admin login of wordpress. I've been searching for quite a while now to resolve this issue.
I constantly got the too many redirect error and my browser was always redirected to wp-admin/install.php.
I already tried the common solutions:

Clear Your Cache and Cookies of browser,

disable .htaccess,

disable all plugins,

disable theme,

adapt wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Check/restore tables of database;

Check wp_options table (did not find a table wp_options (or similar named) in my database)

Nothing worked, in the end I tried the solution to reinstall my website with an old backup (generated from Duplicator – WordPress Migration Plugin) I generated in May. This issue only occurs since a few days so the backup version of the website was certainly a proper working one.

Unfortunately still the same issue appears, the websites keeps redirecting to wp-admin/install.php.

Anyone who has an idea what the solution could be?

Thanks in advance & kind regards!